# regex lookahead but ignore if specific char is found

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

so I have this text

```
onmousedown=
on mousedown=
```

I want to identify all "on" words that are succeded by a "=", but not if there is a space between the "on" word and the "="
=> line 1 should be a match (on)
=> line 2 should not be a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^on[^ ]+=$
```

it matches `on` followed by non-whitespace characters followed by `=`